# Postgresql Window function to look for blocks

Tags: postgresql, aggregate-functions, window-functions

i have a table with the following structure:

```
__________
| history |  
|---------|  
| id      |  
| datetime|
| vehicle |
| zone    |
| speed   |
-----------
```

Im trying to get the following

vehicle      time   zone    StartTime EndTime

```
1       50:00    A    2017-08-22T15:00   2017-08-22T15:50
1       20:00    A    2017-08-22T17:00   2017-08-22T17:20
1       10:00         2017-08-22T18:00   2017-08-22T18:10
```

I'm trying to use window functions to look for the start and end of the stop but can't move to the end of the stop.

can anybody help please?

Update: Added create table and some data, also what i am trying.

```
create table history
( 
id bigserial,
datetx timestamp,
vehicle integer,
zone varchar,
speed integer   
)

insert into history (datetx, vehicle, zone, speed) values ('2017-08-24 00:00', 1, '',50);
insert into history (datetx, vehicle, zone, speed) values ('2017-08-24 00:01', 1, '',45);
insert into history (datetx, vehicle, zone, speed) values ('2017-08-24 00:02', 1, '',30);
insert into history (datetx, vehicle, zone, speed) values ('2017-08-24 00:03', 1, 'A',10);
insert into history (datetx, vehicle, zone, speed) values ('2017-08-24 00:04', 1, 'A',0);
insert into history (datetx, vehicle, zone, speed) values ('2017-08-24 00:24', 1, 'A',0);
insert into history (datetx, vehicle, zone, speed) values ('2017-08-24 00:44', 1, 'A',8);
insert into history (datetx, vehicle, zone, speed) values ('2017-08-24 01:04', 1, '',0);
insert into history (datetx, vehicle, zone, speed) values ('2017-08-24 01:24', 1, 'A',0);
insert into history (datetx, vehicle, zone, speed) values ('2017-08-24 01:44', 1, 'A',0);
insert into history (datetx, vehicle, zone, speed) values ('2017-08-24 02:04', 1, 'A',0);


insert into history (datetx, vehicle, zone, speed) values ('2017-08-24 00:00', 2, '',30);
insert into history (datetx, vehicle, zone, speed) values ('2017-08-24 00:01', 2, '',30);
insert into history (datetx, vehicle, zone, speed) values ('2017-08-24 00:02', 2, 'A',0);
insert into history (datetx, vehicle, zone, speed) values ('2017-08-24 00:03', 2, 'A',10);
insert into history (datetx, vehicle, zone, speed) values ('2017-08-24 00:04', 2, 'A',0);
insert into history (datetx, vehicle, zone, speed) values ('2017-08-24 00:24', 2, 'A',0);
insert into history (datetx, vehicle, zone, speed) values ('2017-08-24 00:44', 2, '',0);
insert into history (datetx, vehicle, zone, speed) values ('2017-08-24 01:04', 2, '',0);
insert into history (datetx, vehicle, zone, speed) values ('2017-08-24 01:24', 2, '',0);
insert into history (datetx, vehicle, zone, speed) values ('2017-08-24 01:44', 2, 'A',0);
insert into history (datetx, vehicle, zone, speed) values ('2017-08-24 02:04', 2, 'A',0);
```

Comment: What do rows in history represent? Is it a table of samples showing the state at frequent intervals, or is it a table of transitions recording changes in zone and speed?

Comment: The "structure" includes data types and constraints. Those are just column names. Ideally show a complete `CREATE TABLE` statement. And always your version of Postgres. And the query you tried, even if it's not working.